# Getting error when trying to backup filesystem

Tags: command-line, backup, tar

There are a bunch of duplicates of this question but none of the fixes worked for me.

I'm trying to make a back up of my entire Ubuntu 16.04 filesystem.

Executing commands like so:

```
$ su root
$ cd /
$ tar --ignore-failed-read -cpzf /backups/fullbackup.tar.gz --exclude=backups --exclude=proc --exclude=tmp --exclude=mnt --exclude=sys --exclude=dev --exclude=run --exclude=/var/lib/ /
tar: /$filename: file changed as we read it tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: Unless `/backups` is excluded from being backed up, you're going to end up trying to copy. `/backups/fullbackup.tar.gz` into `/backups/fullbackup.tar.gz`. It will not fit.

Comment: The backups directory is excluded. Or atleast I think? I did --exclude=backups